# Why does isNaN(123.) return false?

Tags: javascript, validation, function, decimal

Why does the Javascript function call isNaN(123.) return false? (notice the dot (.) after 123). Is this a universally acceptable number or will it cause errors downstream?

I'm validating whether a value is a valid decimal using isNaN along with split. Are there cross-browser issues with isNaN? Should I use a bespoke implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Since 123 **is** a number, the predicate "is **not** a number" is false. What are you expecting?

Comment: In Javascript, 123 == 123. == 123.0

Comment: 123. is not "not a number".  NaN is a very specific numerical "value".  123. is just the same as 123.0.

Comment: yes but is this generally accceptable?

Comment: `123.` is a number in any language that supports floating point values, not just javascript.  It is fairly standard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JavaScript the grammar of a [Numeric Literal](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.3) is expressed like this:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigitsopt ExponentPartopt
```

As you can see the `DecimalDigits` part after the dot is optional (opt suffix).

```
var n = 123.;
typeof n; // "number"
```

I wouldn't recommend the `isNaN` function to detect numbers, since *type coercion* can make some things look *strange*:

```
isNaN(""); // false, a empty string coerces to zero
isNaN("\n\t"); // false, a white-space string coerces to zero
isNaN(true); // false, boolean true coerces to 1
isNaN(false); // false, boolean false coerces to zero
isNaN(new Date); // false, Date objects coerce to its numeric timestamp
// etc...
```

`isNaN` should be used only to compare against `NaN`, since:

```
NaN == NaN; // false!
IsNaN(NaN); // true
```

If you want to detect `Number` objects, `Number` values or "parseable" numeric strings, give a look to [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844) I've posted some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` or (not a number) is a particular floating-point value, meaning **a value that cannot be represented by computers** (using the [IEEE 754 floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).

Crucially for you, the `isNaN()` function makes a best-effort to translate numbers to floating-point, which is why your example returns true.  See, for example:

```
isNaN(100);                   //Returns false
isNaN("100");                 //Returns false
isNaN("ABC");                 //Returns true
isNaN("10C");                 //Returns true
isNaN(Math.sqrt(-1));         //Returns true
```

If you want to access a number such as `"123."` as a float, try using `parseFloat()`:

```
parseFloat("123.");           //Returns 123
```

Furthermore, `123.` is a valid number in javascript, which doesn't require a fractional part after the decimal point.  **So `isNan()` is behaving correctly, and should return false in this case.**

Answer (score 0):

The function is called "is Not a Number". So, this should return false in case you enter a number and true if it isn't. Even with the dot behind it this number is still valid. 123. just validates as 123 or 123.0.

Comment: Actually, it's called "is NaN". The difference is subtle, but important.